# Sendgrid - Receiver can't receive the email sent using php

Tags: php, sendgrid

This is my send_email.php

```
require("../sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");

$from = new SendGrid\Email("Example User", "sample-email@sample.com");
$subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
$to = new SendGrid\Email("Example User", "sample-email@sample.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = ('MY_API_KEY');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
print_r($response->headers());
echo $response->body();
```

When I try to run the "send_email.php" the response is 202 which means it is delivered right? and when I check my Sendgrid Activity Log it says "Delivered". But when the receiver check his/her gmail, he/she does not receive anything.  (I'm testing this in localhost by the way). Please help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Activity log says it is **delivered** or the response is "202", Then it is delivered. Check the spam folder or the junk. Also check trash if it is accidentally deleted by the mail filter. My self got the mail little late in my case. But I use shift mailer.

```
include "/swift/SmtpApiHeader.php";
include "/swift/lib/swift_required.php";

$sendgrid_username = 'xxxx';
$sendgrid_password = 'xxxx';
$to = 'xxxx@xxxx.com';

$transport  = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.sendgrid.net', 587);
$transport->setUsername($sendgrid_username);
$transport->setPassword($sendgrid_password);

$mailer     = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message    = new Swift_Message();
$message->setTo($to);
$message->setCc("xxx@xxxx.ae",);
$message->addBcc("xxxx@xxxx.com");
$message->setFrom($to);
$message->setSubject("Reg: Pending work");

$msg = "Dear worker, Kindly update me the status of the work. Best Regards";

$message->setBody($msg);

try {
  $response = $mailer->send($message);
  print_r($response);
} catch(\Swift_TransportException $e) {
  print_r($e);
  print_r('Bad username / password');
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks man a lot. i see it in spam. your great you save my thesis . :)

Comment: That's fine bhumzky! Cheers!